# Is there a way to reduce the eye shock while switching between high contrast windows in Linux?

Tags: linux, display, eye-strain

Quite often, I jump between my terminal window and a browser and a lot of websites have background colors that contrast with my terminal's background, which is painful for my eyes. Is there a way to reduce this contrast somehow? I was for example thinking that if some window manager could detect that and slowly transition from one color to another, this could be easier to endure.

Comment: https://justgetflux.com/ may help, not quite what you want but similar.

Comment: Maybe you can search a window transition (from active to inactive) that is able to  grey the inactive one... and a slow fade to bright colour for the inverse transition.

Comment: dont know how to do that, but there are usually browser extensions to reverse-video or manipulate colours on web pages.